# How to move videos to specific folders one by one with media player?

Tags: windows-7, media, media-player

I need to rearrange video folder which has hundreds of videos. I'm searching a media player that lets you to organize videos in playlist?

Comment: Odd.  I never saw the point of arranging videos by folders when  a media play will arrange them by metadata. . .

Answer (score 0):

What kind of organizing are you trying to do? Do you want to be able to search by genre or do you just want them in different folders? Take a look at XBMC. I have about 600 DVDs and blurays all in one folder on my media center computer. XBMC will look at the title of the movies and download its information from IMDB.

[image]